# Appending %22 to post varialbles

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, codeigniter-3

I have set of input box like this,

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="gmat1" name="gmat1" placeholder="Eg: 85" >
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="gmpmem1" name=gmpmem1" placeholder="Eg: 5" >
```

then I submit those data to backend using ajax like this,

```
var data = new FormData($('#mr_form')[0]);
  $.ajax({
   url: "xxxxxxx",
   dataType: 'JSON',
   data: data,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
   cache: false,
   type: 'POST',
   success: function (data) {}
});
```

Then I ctach tose data in the backend like,

```
 $data = $this->input->post();
```

My problem is when i'm getting the data

```
[gmat1] => 45645
[gmpmem1%22] => 454
```

I'm getting

> [gmpmem1%22] => 454
>
> %22

%22 has appended to the variable name. I want to remove that part from the variable name. what should i do?

Comment: `name=gmpmem1"` should be `name="gmpmem1"`

Comment: Yes... Got the solution @PraveenKumar thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your input field to

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="gmpmem1" name="gmpmem1" placeholder="Eg: 5" >
```

Use proper quotation